# SSAS Calculated Members's equivalent in Tabular model

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am looking for a way to implement the same idea as SSAS Multidimensional model calculated members in SSAS Tabular model. 
In The Internet Sales sample database, let's consider Location dimension and Sales fact table. I am looking for a way to generate the following report:

```
State          Sales
NY             $100
NJ              $20
CA             $120
WA              $80
East Caost     $120
West Coast     $200
```

I could achieve this in Multidimensional model using calculated member on location dimension (state column) but don't know how to do it in SSAS Tabular.

Can this be done in SSAS Tabular model?

Thanks

Comment: You use measure in Tabular, the will do that, like SUM(table name[column]), the dimension will affected the result based on the relationship with the fact table.